# Adding action to Main toolbar

Tags: qt, action, toolbar

I am having trouble adding action to my main toolbar in a tab widget. The buttons on the toolbar are: Save,Print,Send,Clear & Exit. I have been able to add action to clear and exit via the action editor but cannot figure out how to get the open, print and send to work. The main data fields on my widget are Line edits, comboboxes and spinboxes. Any help would be awesome!
Thank you!

Comment: "cannot figure out how to get the open, print and send to work" What do you expect to happen, and what code have you written so far?

Answer (score 2):

To associate a button with some action, you should do the following:

```
connect(ui->saveTool, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(save()));
```

Where `ui->saveTool` is your button on the toolbar and `save()` a function you want to call pressing the button.

If you also want to use `QAction` for accomplishing this, you should just simply create the action, set a hot-key for it and connect it to the function:

```
QAction saveAct = new QAction("Save", this);
saveAct->setShortcut("Ctrl+S");
connect(saveAct, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(save()));
```

The other way to set functions for a toolbar is via designer: you need to click the right mouse key on the toolButton, get to the slots it supports and use a slot `clicked()`. You will see the `on_saveTool_clicked()` slot created, where you can write your code.